# Dealing with the No source for code error in Python coverage

Tags: pytest, coverage.py

I have a new variant of this old "No source for code" issue.

["No source for code" message in Coverage.py](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2386975/1086346)

Here is the error I see:

```
$ coverage report
No source for code: '/home/pauljohn/GIT/projects/ml_grb/grb/packages/grb/tests/C:\Users\G33987\.conda\envs\grb\lib\site-packages\grb\review\review.py'.
Aborting report output, consider using -i.
```

I'm in Linux, working in a Git repository with a windows teammate "G33987". My current working directory is `/home/pauljohn/GIT/projects/ml_grb/grb/packages/grb/tests`, as you can see, and the virtual environment I'm using is in ~/venv-grb. Notice the super weird thing is that it is looking for a file in my tests folder with an appended full path to a teammate's installed "grb" package folder, "C:\Users\G33987.conda..."

I can add the "-i" flag to ignore problem, but I want to understand and fix.

In the other posts about this issue with coverage.py, the problem was linked to presence of old copy of `.coverage` in tests folder or to presence of `*.pyc` files. I've checked and our Git repository does not track any `pyc` files. However, by mistake it was tracking the original `.coverage` file. But we don't track that anymore and I've manually deleted it between runs.

So far, I have this workflow

1. `coverage erase`
2. `find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm {} \;`
3. `coverage run --source=grb -m pytest .`
4. `coverage report`

I can run `coverage report -i` to ignore issue and the output does give line-by-line reports on the files in my own virtual environment.  But I'm disgusted by ignoring an error.  Where does reference to teammate's virtual environment come from? I'm not using a conda virtual environment, but rather I'm pure Python virtual environment.

```
Python 3.8.5
coverage 5.5
pytest 6.2.2
py 1.10.0
pluggy 0.13.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to delete the .pytest_cache directory before running tests/coverage.

In my case, I believe I was using PyCharm in windows which was running the tests and writing to .pytest_cache with windows paths, then trying to run the project build tools via WSL.

I added the `--cache-clear` flag to pytest to stop this happening again.