# | python coverage report error | no source for code: PATH + '/_remote_module_non_scriptable.py'

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

When I run `coverage run -m pytest tests/` followed by `coverage report` in the terminal

I get the following error:

`No source for code: '/private/var/.../_remote_module_non_scriptable.py'.`

It seems like a similar issue has been resolved already, however I do not understand the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386975/no-source-for-code-message-in-coverage-py).

Can a friendly soul help me understand what might be the cause of the problem?

Comment: There are several simple and concrete suggestions in that post.  (1) Delete all the .pyc files, (2) Do `nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase` to accomplish the same thing.  (3) Do `coverage xml -i`.  Have you done any of those?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts ,`coverage xml -i` worked for me. Generally, the `-i` just skipped the files it failed on (in my case the _remote_module_non_scriptable.py), so the prettier output `coverage report -i` also worked. Thanks.